# Read ExtendedProperties from Outlook Add-In

Tags: javascript, outlook-addin, exchangewebservices, extended-properties

I am currently setting custom `ExtendedProperties` on a `CalendarFolder` using EWS Managed API (C#):

```
myCalendar.SetExtendedProperty(customExtendedProperty, true);
```

I can also use the Managed API to load those settings when I bind the `CalendarFolder`:

```
var myCalendar = CalendarFolder.Bind(service, folderId, requestedPropertySet);
```

I would next like to read these same `ExtendedProperties`, but from an Outlook Add-In using the Office JavaScript libraries.

From the looks of the the Outlook library does not expose any methods off of `Office.context.item` to access the `ExtendedProperties`.

Are there methods in the library that allow me to access this? If not, can I use the schema approach which has the GUID in the URL path (`"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/yourProp"`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access your own custom properties on a folder in Addin you need to use the makeEwsRequestAsync https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.context.mailbox.html#makeEwsRequestAsync to do a GetFolder in your Addin. To get the correct SOAP message just enabling tracing in you EWS Managed API code which will output the SOAP used https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495632(v=exchg.150).aspx which you can these transpose. The one thing to be aware of is the security requirements for making a makeEwsRequestAsync in your app eg ReadWriteMailbox http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/understanding-outlook-add-in-permissions

Comment: I had no idea there was a way to profile the SOAP messages that get sent. That was the missing piece. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As of now (July 2018), the preferred way to access custom ExtendedProperties when writing an Outlook add-in is to use the [ExtendedProperties REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/extended-properties-rest-operations).

There is some sample code showing how to use the API with the Office add-in JavaScript library, available from [Office Dev Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/use-rest-api).

To use the API, you need to get an auth token from the current Outlook mailbox. This can be done using the `Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync()` method, with keyword parameter `{isRest: true}`.You should also use the `Office.context.mailbox.restUrl` property to get the correct base URL for the API call.

There are a few ways to actually make a REST API call from JavaScript, but the simplest way to do it clientside is with an AJAX call. In your example, this would look like:

```
const getMessageUrl = Office.context.mailbox.restUrl
  + "/v2.0/me/mailFolders/" + <folder id> + "?"
  + "$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties"
  + "($filter=PropertyId eq '<property id>')";

$.ajax({
  url: getMessageUrl,
  datatype: 'json',
  headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + <auth token>}
}).then(item => {
  // your code here
})
```

If you have a GUID for your property, then <property id> will look like the following:

```
"String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name yourProp"
```

If you're like me and were trying to access a property that predates the GUID rules, then your <property id> may look like this:

```
"String 0x007D"
```